# What is the best way to encode and upload a file to server using python3?

Tags: python-3.5

I followed the following encode method. Can anyone suggest me best way to encode, so that there will be no loss while decoding?

```
with open(f, "rb") as pdf_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "encoding" a PDF file? You can just upload the file as it is.

Comment: I have to store the file in encoded format only at server side, So I have to encode before sending to the server.

Comment: Yes, but encoding *to what*?

Comment: Anyway, concerning the code you've posted, is there any problem with it?